# Inherit interface resolvers in Apollo Federation

Tags: apollo, apollo-federation

Is there a way to use interface resolver inheritance with Apollo Federation?
I've found `inheritResolversFromInterfaces: true` which is an option for `makeExecutableSchema`. I couldn't find a way though to apply this option to a federated schema.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `addResolveFunctionsToSchema` from `graphql-tools` (or `addResolversToSchema` from @graphql-tools/schema but I’m not sure if it works with this version) like this:

```js
  const federatedSchema = buildSubgraphSchema(typeDefs);
  const schema = addResolveFunctionsToSchema({
    inheritResolversFromInterfaces: true,
    resolvers,
    schema: federatedSchema,
  });
```